# Requirejs - using singleton object, unable to get the returning template

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am starting a app (i am new for requirejs) requirejs singleton model of app... basically i am passing array of templates to my utilities js, and assigning the templates to appropriate views...

i use :

app.js,singleton.js(to return object), index.js for implement index page template, utilities for assigning templates to appropriate views...

But in the index.js, while i console this.template... i am getting a result as "function (n){return e.call(this,n,w)} " - i understand that my approach is wrong.. can any once give me correct way to me.. or highlight me the wrong what i do pelase..?

Thanks in Advance..

Here is my all js files:

app.js:-

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        "jquery"    : 'lib/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        "underscore": "lib/underscore-min",
        "backbone"  : "lib/backbone-min",
        "singleton" : "utils/singleton",
        "model"     : "models/model",
        "index"     : "views/index",
        "utils"     : "utils/utils",
    },
    shim:{
        "underscore":{
            exports: '_'
        },
        "backbone":{
            exports: 'Backbone',
            deps:['underscore']
        },
        "utils" : {
            deps:['index'],
            deps:['model']
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery","underscore","backbone","singleton","utils","index"],function ($,_,Backbone,obj) {
    obj.makeTemp(['index']);
});
```

singleton.js (just returns the object)

```
define(function () {
    var EDMS = EDMS || {};
    return EDMS;
})
```

utilities.js (where i assign the templates)

```
define(["underscore", "singleton","model","index"],function (_,obj,model) {

    var EDMS = obj || {};

        EDMS.makeTemp = function(views){
            $.each(views, function(index,view){
                if(view){
                        var temp = $.get('templates/' + view + '.html')
                        .done(function(data){
                            EDMS[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
                            new EDMS.index;
                        })
                }else{
                        console.log("No template found!")
                    }

                });
        }

    return EDMS;

})
```

finally my index.js, where i should suppose to get the template, which is assigned by utilities.js

```
define(["singleton","underscore","backbone","utils"],function (obj,_,Backbone) {

        var EDMS = obj || {};

        EDMS.index = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize:function(){
                console.log(this.template);
                            error i am getting as "function (n){return e.call(this,n,w)} "
            }
        });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works for me:

```
define(['singleton',"underscore","backbone"],function (obj,_,Backbone) {

    window.EDMS = obj || {};

    var temps = function(views){
        var tempts = [];
        $.each(views, function(i,view){
            var data = $.get("templates/"+views+".html");
            data.done(function(res){
                EDMS[views].prototype.template = _.template(res);
                new EDMS.index;
            });
        })
    };
    return temps;
});
```

Thanks for all.